# Issue with creating cursor twice

Tags: android, cursor, textview, indexoutofboundsexception

Really confused regarding the use of a cursor.

I have one activity that works fine, the code is as follows:

```
public class AreaActivity extends ListActivity {

private TextView secondaryTitle;
private Button newArea;
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;

private RMDbAdapter rmDbHelper;
private AlertDialog clickOptionsDialog;
private long inspectionId;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_area);
    rmDbHelper = new RMDbAdapter(this);
    rmDbHelper.open();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    inspectionId = i.getLongExtra("Intent_InspectionID", -1);
    setUpViews();
    setLongClick();

    // Get a Cursor for the list items
    Cursor listCursor = rmDbHelper.fetchAllAreasForInspection(inspectionId);
    startManagingCursor(listCursor);           

    // set the custom list adapter     
    setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listCursor));



}

private void setUpViews() {
    secondaryTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondary_title);
    final Cursor cursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchInspection(inspectionId);
    String inspectionRef = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF)), "Reference unknown"); 
    String companyName = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY)), "company unknown"); 
    cursor.close();
    final String secondaryTitleText = inspectionRef + ", " + companyName;
    secondaryTitle.setText(secondaryTitleText);
    newArea = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_area);
    newArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                     
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createArea();
        }
    }); 

}
```

The cursor gets the information from the database ok then checks it is not empty (using a code in separate class as recommended to me on this site) and sets the text in the `TextView`.

However, when I use this exact code in the next activity to do the same thing, I get the error:

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0..

The code is the same, so I guess it is an issue with duplicating a cursor or not using `moveToFirst` but nothing I do seems to solve the problem.

Comment: i guess inspectionId is different ?

Comment: njzk2 - spot the obvious mistake eh.  Thank you, I had assigned the wrong value to inspectionId when I passed it in the Intent.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue thanks to njzk2 - stupid error when I passed the inspectionId to the Intent..